# How do I disable Transformations in TYPO3 RTE Editor?

Tags: editor, typo3, rte

I created a custom extension for TYPO3 CMS.
It basically does some database queries to get text from database.
As I have seen, TYPO3 editor, transforms data before storing it in database so for example a link `<a href="....." >Link</a>` is stored as `<link href>My Link Text</link>` and so on for many tags like this.
when I query data from DB, I get it as it is stored in DB (`<link href>My Link Text</link>`)
so links are not displayed as they shoud. They display as normal text..

As far as I know there are two ways to go:

1. disable RTE transformations (how to do that?)
2. use lib.parseFunc_RTE (which i have no Idea how to configure it properly)

any idea?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just so if anyone else runs into this problem,

**I found one way to resolve** it by using `pi_RTEcssText()` function inside my extension file:

```
$outputText=$this->pi_RTEcssText( $value['bodytext'] );
```

where `$value['bodytext']` is the string I get from the database-query in my extension.

This function seems to process data and return the full HTML (links, paragraphs and other tags inculded).

***Note:***
If you haven't already, it requires to include this file:

```
require_once(PATH_tslib.'class.tslib_pibase.php');
```

on the top of your extension file.

That's it basically.

Comment: No need to require this file. TYPO3 ships with an autoloader.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you're not using Extbase and Fluid? Just as a reference, if you are using Extbase and Fluid for your extension you can render text from the RTE using Fluid:

```
<f:format.html>{bodytext}</f:format.html>
```

This uses lib.parseFunc_RTE to render the RTE text as HTML. You can also tell it to use a different TypoScript object for the rendering:

```
<f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.my_parseFunc">{bodytext}</f:format.html>
```

Useful documentation:

- [parseFunc](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Parsefunc/Index.html)
- [Fluid format.html](http://wiki.typo3.org/Fluid#f:format.html)

Comment: The attribute is actually called parseFuncTSPath, not parseFunc. The full syntax for the standard RTE transform would be <f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc">{bodytext}</f:format.html>

Comment: Good catch! I updated my answer. By default it uses the standard RTE transform, so no need to include that again.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem, but using EXTBASE the function "pi_RTEcssText" ist not available anymore. Well maybe it is, but I didn't know how to include it.

Anyway, here's my solution using EXTBASE:

```
$this->cObj = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject();
$bodytext = $this->cObj->parseFunc($bodyTextFromDb, $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['lib.']['parseFunc_RTE.']);
```

This way I get the RTE formatted text.

Comment: thanks for the good attitude of sharing for others. I don't use Typo3 anymore because I quit my job 10 months ago (I was never really quite into Typo3, my friend was), but sharing your solution might save others many hours or days of frustration :)

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do it by **configuring the included typoscript**:

```
# Creates persistent ParseFunc setup for non-HTML content. This is recommended to use (as a reference!)
lib.parseFunc {
makelinks = 1
makelinks.http.keep = {$styles.content.links.keep}
makelinks.http.extTarget < lib.parseTarget
makelinks.http.extTarget =
makelinks.http.extTarget.override = {$styles.content.links.extTarget}
makelinks.mailto.keep = path
tags {
    link = TEXT
    link {
        current = 1
        typolink.parameter.data = parameters : allParams
        typolink.extTarget < lib.parseTarget
        typolink.extTarget =
        typolink.extTarget.override = {$styles.content.links.extTarget}
        typolink.target < lib.parseTarget
        typolink.target =
        typolink.target.override = {$styles.content.links.target}
        parseFunc.constants =1
    }
}
allowTags = {$styles.content.links.allowTags}
```

And denied tag **link**:

```
denyTags = link

sword = <span class="csc-sword">|</span>
constants = 1

nonTypoTagStdWrap.HTMLparser = 1
nonTypoTagStdWrap.HTMLparser {
    keepNonMatchedTags = 1
    htmlSpecialChars = 2
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @David. This question is from 2 years ago and I no longer work with Typo3 since I quit my day job - I almost forgot everything about it. But I hope it helps someone else that may come across ;)